# Java Generics and type transform

Tags: java, generics

I just start learning Generics of Java. It confused me when I try to read some sample examples, just as below. I know it's something related to the type erasure, but I can not figure out what's going wrong.

```
package graph;
import java.util.*;

public class JustTest<T> {  
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ArrayQueue<String> q = new ArrayQueue<String>(); 
        q.offer(new String("string_1"));
        q.offer(new String("string_2"));

        Object[] ob = q.getArray();
        System.out.println(ob);

        // The lines below went wrong when running
        // Error information: 
        //java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
        String[] str = q.getArray();
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}


class ArrayQueue<T> {

    private static final int MINIMUM_SIZE = 1024;

    private T[] array = (T[]) new Object[MINIMUM_SIZE];
    private int lastIndex = 0;

    public T[] getArray () {
        return array;
    }

    public T getElement () {
        return array[0];
    }

    public boolean offer(T value) {

        array[lastIndex % array.length] = value;
        lastIndex++;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Satchel, I made an update to the answer, I hope it works for you, let me know

Answer (score 1):

> Update

I missed up something last time, if you are learning generics, just picked up a little twisted example, you probably need to start with some classes like Pair, but well.

> I Made this changes to your ArrayQueue class:

The @SuppressWarnings is added to avoid the error casting, because we know that the cast we made here manually is right, so, suppress this warning is fine in this case.

I also added two constructors, one parameter and two parameters, the first parameter is the `Class<T> c` is the type you will say it will have in the moment you create it, and the second one is if you want another sizes for your array.

in this line:

```
array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(c, MINIMUM_SIZE);
```

is how I made possible to create the generic array, with the Array.newInstance method, you can tell the class and the size, and the type is given as parameter, that's the trick.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
class ArrayQueue<T> {

  private static final int MINIMUM_SIZE = 1024;
  private T[] array;
  private int lastIndex = 0;

  public ArrayQueue(Class<T> c){
    array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(c, MINIMUM_SIZE);
  }

  public ArrayQueue(Class<T> c, int size){
    array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(c, size);
  }

  public T[] getArray () {
    return array;
  }

  public T getElement () {
    return array[0];
  }

  public boolean offer(T value) {

    array[lastIndex % array.length] = value;
    lastIndex++;
    return true;
  }
}
```

> And in the main class, for testing it:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
        ArrayQueue<String> q = new ArrayQueue<String>(String.class); 
        q.offer(new String("string_1"));
        q.offer(new String("string_2"));

        String[] ob = q.getArray();
        System.out.println(ob[0]);
        System.out.println(ob[1]);

        // The lines below went wrong when running
        // Error information: 
        //java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
        String[] str = q.getArray();
        System.out.println(str[0]);
  }
```

Comment: I don't believe you've tested this solution.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem you are right, I thought it was just simple as change some types, but it was a little more Twisted, I made an update for the answer now. I hope you find it ok.

Comment: I think it works now, which it didn't yesterday.  But I don't feel inclined to remove my downvote.  You haven't explained what's going on.  You haven't explained _why_ you made the changes that you did.  An answer on Stack Overflow needs to be more than just a code dump; otherwise nobody learns anything from it.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem mmh, ok I agree, I thought it was clear, I will update again

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, thank's for all the advices, I'm new answering questions here, I'm still learning, I'm active since little more than a month, but with some help I learn every day. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the unchecked cast in your `ArrayQueue` class:

```
private T[] array = (T[]) new Object[MINIMUM_SIZE];
```

You basically say here that an `Object[]` is actually a `T[]`, but this cast is 'unchecked' so there is never a check at runtime. If there was, this cast would fail, since an `Object[]` is *not* a `T[]` unless `T` is `Object`. But since the cast is unchecked, the program doesn't crash on this line.

The program crashes on the line where the compiler inserts an implicit cast, at the point where `T` is a known concrete type:

```
String[] str = q.getArray();
```

Here you go from `T[]` to `String[]`, so the compiler will insert an implicit cast here:

```
String[] str = (String[]) q.getArray();
```

And this is where it blows up, since your earlier cast to `T[]` was faulty.

With the interface you currently have, the most convenient solution would be to pass a reference to a constructor of `T[]`, so you can *actually* create a `T[]`:

```
class ArrayQueue<T> {

    private static final int MINIMUM_SIZE = 1024;

    private T[] array;

    ...

    public ArrayQueue(IntFunction<T[]> arrayCons) {
        array = arrayCons.apply(MINIMUM_SIZE);
    }
```

...

```
ArrayQueue<String> q = new ArrayQueue<>(String[]::new);  // passing a constructor reference
```

Or use a similar solution to what API `Collection`s do, using an `Object[]` instead of a `T[]` array, and require a reference to a `T[]` constructor when calling `getArray`:

```
class ArrayQueue<T> {

    private static final int MINIMUM_SIZE = 1024;

    private Object[] array = new Object[MINIMUM_SIZE];

    ...

    public T[] getArray(IntFunction<T[]> arrayCons) {
        T[] ret = arrayCons.apply(size()); // implement size
        System.arrayCopy(array, firstIndex, ret, 0, size());
        return ret;
    }

    public T getElement() {
        return (T) array[0]; // a safe unchecked cast, since you only put Ts into the array.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

During runtime, `T`s are replaced by `Object`, unless there is a bounding type. This means that

```
private T[] array = (T[]) new Object[MINIMUM_SIZE];
```

actually becomes

```
private Object[] array = new Object[MINIMUM_SIZE];
```

So when you call `getArray`, you get an array of `Object`, which can't be assigned a reference of type `String[]`. Hence the `ClassCastException`.

Each element in the array can, by itself, be cast from `Object` to `String` **(specifically because it's `String`)**, but the array as a whole can't be cast.

Which is why you get

```
[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
```

The `[L` means it's an array.

To get them as strings, you can do this thing:

```
String[] str = Arrays.toList(q.getArray()).stream().map(Object::toString()).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray();
```

Which should work.

Comment: I agree with you that when running, the code below \\ `private T[] array = (T[]) new Object[MINIMUM_SIZE];` will be translated as    `private Object[] array = new Object[MINIMUM_SIZE];`

Comment: The problem is, will `public T[] getArray () ` be also translated into `public Object[] getArray () `. If so, this means all 'T' will be translated as 'Object'. Is that right?

Comment: @Satchel yes. That is java generics for you :P